# Why is my Matlab hgtransform matrix invalid?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, homogenous-transformation

I am attempting to apply a transform matrix by setting the `'Matrix'` property of a matlab hgtransform object. The transform matrix is below:

```
 866.0254e-003   500.0000e-003   0.0000e+000   500.0000e-003
 500.0000e-003  -866.0254e-003   0.0000e+000   500.0000e-003
 0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     1.0000e+000     0.0000e+000
 0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     1.0000e+000
```

This particular matrix is intended to represent a translation

(0.5, 0.5, 0)

and rotation around the Z axis of pi/6.

When I try to do this:

```
% make a unit box
sx = 1;
sy = 1;
sz = 1;
shapeData.Vertices = [ -sx/2, -sy/2, -sz/2;
                        sx/2, -sy/2, -sz/2;
                        sx/2,  sy/2, -sz/2;
                       -sx/2,  sy/2, -sz/2;
                       -sx/2, -sy/2,  sz/2;
                        sx/2, -sy/2,  sz/2;
                        sx/2,  sy/2,  sz/2;
                       -sx/2,  sy/2,  sz/2; ];

shapeData.Faces = [ 1, 4, 3, 2;
                         1, 5, 6, 2;
                         2, 6, 7, 3;
                         7, 8, 4, 3;
                         8, 5, 1, 4;
                         8, 7, 6, 5 ];

figure;
axes;
transformObject = hgtransform (gca);

patchObject = patch (gca, ...
                    'Faces', shapeData.Faces, ...
                    'Vertices', shapeData.Vertices, ...
                    'FaceColor', 'red', ...
                    'FaceAlpha', 1.0, ...
                    'EdgeColor', 'none',        ...
                    'FaceLighting', 'gouraud',     ...
                    'AmbientStrength', 0.15, ...
                    'Parent', transformObject);

M = [ ...
         866.0254e-003   500.0000e-003   0.0000e+000   500.0000e-003; ...
         500.0000e-003  -866.0254e-003   0.0000e+000   500.0000e-003; ...
         0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     1.0000e+000     0.0000e+000; ...
         0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     1.0000e+000; ...
        ];

set ( transformObject, 'Matrix', M );
```

I get the error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.Transform/set
Invalid value for Matrix property
```

Why?

## EDIT

The code that generated the transform matrix. First you need the following class which constructs orientation (rotation) matrices:

```
classdef orientmat

    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = protected)

        orientationMatrix;
    end

    methods

        function this = orientmat (spectype, spec)
        % orentmat constructor
        %
        % Syntax
        %
        % om = orientmat (spectype, spec)
        %
        % Input
        %
        % 

            switch spectype

                case 'orientation'

                    this.orientationMatrix = spec;

                case 'euler'

                    this.orientationMatrix = SpinCalc('EA123toDCM', rad2deg (spec), eps (), 1);

                case 'euler123'

                    this.orientationMatrix = SpinCalc('EA123toDCM', rad2deg (spec), eps (), 1);

                case 'euler321'

                    this.orientationMatrix = SpinCalc('EA321toDCM', rad2deg (spec), eps (), 1);

                case 'vector'
                    % axis and angle (angle in rad = norm of matrix)
                    wcrs = [ 0         spec(3) -spec(2)
                            -spec(3)        0   spec(1)
                             spec(2)  -spec(1)       0] ;   

                    this.orientationMatrix = expm (wcrs);

                case '2vectors'

                    % normalise the fisr vector
                    spec.vec1 = this.unit (spec.vec1);
                    spec.vec2 = this.unit (spec.vec2);

                    spec.vec3 = cross (spec.vec1, spec.vec2);

                    spec.vec2 = this.unit (cross (this.unit (spec.vec3), spec.vec1));

                    switch spec.vec1axis

                        case 1
                            X = spec.vec1;
                            if spec.vec2axis == 2
                                Y = spec.vec2;
                                Z = spec.vec3;
                            elseif spec.vec2axis == 3
                                Y = spec.vec3;
                                Z = spec.vec2;
                            end

                        case 2
                            Y = spec.vec1;
                            if spec.vec2axis == 1
                                X = spec.vec2;
                                Z = spec.vec3;
                            elseif spec.vec2axis == 3
                                X = spec.vec3;
                                Z = spec.vec2;
                            end

                        case 3
                            Z = spec.vec1;
                            if spec.vec2axis == 2
                                X = spec.vec2;
                                Y = spec.vec3;
                            elseif spec.vec2axis == 3
                                X = spec.vec3;
                                Y = spec.vec2;
                            end

                    end

                    this.orientationMatrix = [ X, Y, Z ];

            end 

        end

    end

    % operator overloading
    methods 

        function om = plus (om1, om2)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', om1.orientationMatrix + om2.orientationMatrix);

        end

        function om = minus (om1, om2)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', om1.orientationMatrix - om2.orientationMatrix);

        end

        function om = times (om1, om2)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', om1.orientationMatrix .* om2.orientationMatrix);

        end

        function om = mtimes (om1, om2)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', om1.orientationMatrix * om2.orientationMatrix);

        end

        function om = double (om1)

            om = om1.orientationMatrix;

        end

        function om = uminus (om1)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', -om1.orientationMatrix);

        end

        function om = uplus (om1)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', +om1.orientationMatrix);

        end

        function om = transpose (om1)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', om1.orientationMatrix.');

        end

        function om = ctranspose (om1)

            om = mbdyn.pre.orientmat ('orientation', om1.orientationMatrix');

        end

    end

    methods (Access = private)

        function out = unit (self, vec)

            out = vec ./ norm (vec);

        end

    end


end
```

Then do:

```
om = orientmat ('2vectors', struct ('vec1axis', 1, 'vec1', [cos(pi/6);sin(pi/6);0], 'vec2axis', 3, 'vec2', [0;0;1]));

M = [ om.orientationMatrix, [0.5; 0.5; 0]; 0, 0, 0, 1 ];
```

Now there may be an issue with the rotation not actually being what I intend, but as far as I can see it is still a valid transformation matrix?

Comment: Can you provide MATLAB version? this code fails on 2014B

Comment: Do you have the code that generates your transformation matrix?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, it's R2016b not sure what the earliest version it will work in is.

Comment: @Suever I added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that Matlab only accepts non-negative scaling terms, see [Transforms Supported by hgtransform](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/transform-objects-within-a-group.html)

Comment: Hi, are you meaning that your `M` has negative scaling terms. It looks like to me that `M` only contains rotation and translation. Did I miss sth? Thanks!

Comment: The [diagonal of the matrix is the scaling matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)), so even if you only intend rotation and translation, if you have terms on the diagonal you implicitly have scaling as well, or at least, that seems to be what Matlab thinks. Perhaps it would be more accurate to say Matlab doesn't like non-negative terms on the diagonal of the transform matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right, I don't think that "diagonal of the matrix is the scaling matrix", neither. Consider an arbitrary rotation matrix with negative diagonal. Obvious it is not doing any scaling. In addition, I observed that in my warnings, the targeted hgtransform matrix has positive diagonals. Are there any other possible materials on this you can share?